# Is the duality in linear programming related to category theory?

Tags: optimization, reference-request, category-theory, linear-programming

Usually in mathematics when there is some kind of duality it can be phrased in terms of category theory. Is this the case for the duality in linear programming (or for other kind of dualities in optimization)? Has there been attempts to formalize this kind of duality and linear programming/optimization using category theory?